# How to create interchangeable class types for android fake testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to create a fake class for my repository to test a view model.

As far as I understood, the key element here is to create two classes with a common interface so both classes would contain the same methods.
The problem is I get a Type mismatch when trying to initialize an object.
I tried to do the same in a simplified manner:

```
class fakeClass1 : fakeInterface {
override fun getAllData(): String {
    return ""
}}}


class fakeClass2 : fakeInterface {
override fun getAllData(): String {
    return ""
}}

interface fakeInterface {
fun getAllData(): String}

val fakeClass: fakeClass1 = fakeClass2()
```

But that didn't work either.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
I was wrong to think that those two classes should be interchangeable.

I solved it by making the ViewModel take the common interface in its constructor instead of the actual repository class. This allows the ViewModel to take any class which implement this interface as it's repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think you worked it out, but just so you're clear (this is an important, fundamental thing!)

```
val fakeClass: fakeClass1 = fakeClass2()
```

This is defining a variable called `fakeClass` that refers to an object with the `fakeClass1` type. Then you assign an object with the `fakeClass2` type.

But a `fakeClass2` **is not** a `fakeClass1`, neither is a superclass of the other, so you can't treat one as the other. Your example is simple, but imagine you added `coolFunction()` to `fakeClass1` - they'd now happen to have different structures, and trying to call that method on an object that doesn't have it would cause a crash.

The only thing those classes have in common, is that they both have the `fakeInterface` type - they **are** `fakeInterface`s, and that guarantees they implement the stuff in that interface (your `getAllData` function in this case). So if you treat them both as that type instead:

```
val fakeClass: fakeInterface = fakeClass2()
```

you can use either one, because they're both `fakeInterface`s (similar to how `Int`s and `Double`s are different but they're both `Number`s). Because `fakeClass` is now a `fakeInterface`, you can **only** access the functions and properties that a `fakeInterface` has - you can't call `coolFunction()` even if you happened to pass in a `fakeClass1`, because `fakeInterface` doesn't have that.

(You could cast the variable to `fakeClass1`, basically saying "oh by the way this object is *actually* this type as well", but at that point the type system can't guarantee you're correct unless you're explicitly checking `fakeClass is fakeClass1`, and it'll warn you if that's the case)

The [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) are pretty good and they'll give you an overview about how the types each form a kind of "contract" you work with